What does .transform('size') do?
I had a user help me solve a pandas question on here previously.  I'm currently re-reading the answer and realized that I have no idea what .transform('size') from df.groupby(g).transform('size').le(N+1) means.  I've looked around on google but wasn't able to find anything related to what "size" means for transform.
Could someone help shed some light?
this is my previous question:
back fill data on the condition that there is a 1 located <=2 rows previously to your current location

Did you read the user guide? Group by § The transform() method and § Built-in aggregation methods

Does this effectively answer your question? What does .transform('first') do?

wjandrea,
thank you very much.  I did read the userGuide, but didn't find the Built-in aggregation methods.  Thank you for helping me locate that section.  I think that more or less answers my question thank you very much.
